# Verify that $4r^3+r=\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4-\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Must I verify that Left hand side(LHS)= Right hand side(RHS)or can I prove that RHS= LHS?

I don’t know how to prove from LHS=RHS. How to separate the $4r^3+r$ into two terms, i.e. $\displaystyle\Bigl(r+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^4-\Bigl(r-\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^4$

After verifying, I will need to find $$\sum_{r=1}^n (4r^3+r)$$

This is a summation of finite series question.

Comment: Can you *expand* $(r+\frac{1}{2})^4$ and $(r-\frac{1}{2})^4$ ?

Comment: @MartinR yes, it’s not a problem, but how to verify from LHS to RHS?

Comment: Well, then expand the RHS  and verify that it is equal to the LHS.

Comment: Equality is *symmetric:* LHS=RHS if and only if RHS=LHS.

Comment: @MartinR just to be sure, there is no way to verify from LHS to RHS, is there?

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. Of course you can start with the LHS and write it as $4 r^3+r = \bigl(r^4+2 r^3 +3r^2/2+r/2+1/16 \bigr) - \bigl(r^4-2 r^3 +3r^2/2-r/2+1/16\bigr) = (r+1/2)^4 - (r-1/2)^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, the right-hand side is$$(r^2+\tfrac14+r)^2-(r^2+\tfrac14-r)^2=(2r^2+\tfrac12)(2r)=4r^3+r.$$

Answer (score 2):

$(x+y)^{4}-(x-y)^{3}=8x^{3}y+8xy^3$

Just substitute $x=r$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$ to obtain

$4r^{3}+r=(r+\frac{1}{2})^{4}-(r-\frac{1}{2})^{4}$

As for the infinite sum,

$\sum_{r=1}^{n}({4r^{3}+r})=-\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^4+\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^4 - \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^4+...+\left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)^4$

$\sum_{r=1}^{n}(4r^{3}+r)=\left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right)^4-\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^4$

Answer (score 1):

Can you notice that both sides of the equation are polynomials of degree less than or equal to $3$? If yes then note that if they are equal for more than $3$ values of $r$ they are equal identically.

Just put $r=0,r=1/2,r=-1/2,r=3/2$ and check equality of both sides and you are done.

The above is a general technique to prove equality of two polynomials.

Another approach is to factor the RHS as $$((r+1/2)^2+(r-1/2)^2)((r+1/2)^2-(r-1/2)^2)$$ which equals $$(2(r^2+(1/2)^2))(4r(1/2))$$ or $$(4r^2+1)r=4r^3+r$$

Comment: I think this is the simplest answer. It avoids algebraic manipulation altogether.

Comment: @KKZiomek: glad you like it. One must avoid tedious calculations wherever possible as they are error-prone. The choice of four values of $r$ is also based on same principle.

Answer (score 0):

Render

$4r^3+r=(2r^2+\frac{1}{2})(2r)$

and define

$(2r^2+\frac{1}{2})=u+v$

$2r=u-v$

Solving the latter equations for $u$ and $v$ and identifying $(u+v)(u-v)$ with $u^2-v^2$ then yields

$4r^3+r=(r^2+r+\frac14)^2-(r^2-r+\frac14)^2$

and since the arguments of the squares on the right are themselves perfect squares, this is also a difference of fourth powers:

$\color{blue}{4r^3+r=(r+\frac12)^4-(r-\frac12)^4}$

Answer (score 0):

Using the first identity,

$$\sum_{r=1}^n(4r^3+r)=\sum_{r=1}^n\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4-\sum_{r=1}^n\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4
\\=\sum_{r=1}^n\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4-\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4$$

and by telescoping, this is

$$\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4.$$

---

To establish the identity, factor the differences of squares

$$\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4-\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\\
=\left(\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)
\left(\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\left(\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\\
=\left(2r^2+\frac24\right)\cdot2r\cdot1.$$